# How to get a reference to ActionBar MenuItem in Android Test Project

Tags: android, android-menu, android-testing

I want to get a reference to a MenuItem from the ActionBar of an activity for unit testing purpose.

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception{
    super.setUp();
    viewContacts = getActivity();

    addContactsBtn = (MenuItem)viewContacts.findViewById(R.id.action_add);
    searchBtn = (MenuItem)viewContacts.findViewById(R.id.action_search);

}
```

where, action_add and action_search are defined in my menu.xml file as follows

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"/>
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    android:title="@string/action_add"/>
```

The test case throws ClassCastException-

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView cannot be cast to
>   android.view.MenuItem at
>   com.example.simplecontacts.test.ViewContactsTest.setUp(ViewContactsTest.java:24)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
>   at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
>   at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)

I researched ways to obtain a reference to a MenuItem. Usual way to do this is via the Menu/MenuItem arguments passed into the onOptionsItemSelected, onPrepareOptionsMenu methods. That is perfectly logical in the **application project** itself but how should I obtain MenuItem reference inside the **test project**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it turns out that casting them into View objects is sufficient for unit testing purpose. So the code will be like so

```
addContactsBtn = (View)viewContacts.findViewById(R.id.action_add);
searchBtn = (View)viewContacts.findViewById(R.id.action_search);
```

Comment: Wow! Didn't expect that to work but it does. Simply calling `findViewById(int id)` on the activity with the id of the menu item does the job!